# Is the stress-energy tensor $T$ from Einstein field equations invertible?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the Einstein field equations is it possible to write the stress-energy tensor T_uv in inverted form in the product of Ricci curvature on the LHS so that you get only constants on one side of the equation and tensors on other.
Can it even be inverted and what can be done to take it to the LHS of the equation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariant vs. contravariant definition of the Energy-Momentum tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705608/)

Comment: *product of Ricci curvature* The product of Ricci curvature and *what*? Are you trying to put both the Einstein curvature tensor and the energy-momentum-stress tensor on the left side and just have constants on the right side? If so, why?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do. Just trying to play with it to understand it better.